# JQuery Versions Clashing

Tags: javascript, jquery, libraries

I have 2 scripts running different versions of jQuery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The other uses:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

When I have them both the one that needs 1.7.2 falls apart, and when I remove 1.3.2 my other script falls apart.

Which library includes both of these?

Comment: What JS do you have that would break if 1.3.2 isn't present? You only want to be using 1 copy of jQuery, find out what needs to be tweaked and upgrade the jQuery to fit the newer version.

Comment: Anything that really *needs* a version of jQuery that old is probably not worth using.

Comment: It is a bad practice to have two same libraries with different versions. A library is updated because its code is better than the last version. Since this is true for most libraries(including jQuery) you should find your errors and then refactor your code and port it to the most recent features.

Comment: This jquery countdown breaks when 1.3.2 is present: http://rendro.github.io/countdown/ This script seems to break if any other version of jquery is present.

Comment: Don't include jQuery 1.3.2, only include 1.7.2. How does that affect things? (don't forget to include 1.7.2 before any of your other scripts)

Comment: @KevinB then the other script no longer works. The other script is a keep div at top after scroll and it uses 1.3.2. I may have to update.

Comment: What did it error with? upgrading from 1.3.2 to 1.7.2 shouldn't be very difficult.

Comment: I just updated the old script to use the 1.7.2 so it's good now.